# setState() in componentDidMount() throwing an error in APK

Tags: react-native, expo, es6-promise, react-state-management

I'm currently working on a project, using Expo 35 (or React Native 0.59)

My code works when tested in IOS simulator and ADV, using `expo start`.

However, it somehow throws an error and closes abruptly by itself when tested in APK (`expo build:android`).

Here's my code.

```
  componentDidMount() {

        Promise.all([
            4~5 Axios requests...             
        ])
            .then(() => {

                this.setState({
                    ...
                    loaded: true,
                    ...
                });
            })

    }
```

Any idea to fix the issue?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: So, when I first try to navigate to the screen where the code is executed, it restarts. When I navigate to the screen again, the screen never updates. No error message appears (my explanation wasn't clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` launches before rendering the component and `setState` will re-render the component and it will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the app updates the screen and it's wrong.

You can do something like this instead:

```
_execute = ()=>{
   Promise.all([
            4~5 Axios requests...             
        ])
            .then(() => {

                this.setState({
                    ...
                    loaded: true,
                    ...
                });
            })
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._execute()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I checked that ```Promise``` properly returns its result. So, it is very likely that somehow ```setState()``` doesn't trigger re-rendering

Comment: It shouldn't  happen , could you please provide me with the full code , let check it for you .

Comment: So far, I verified that if the app is tested on ADV or iOS simulator, works fine. However, if tested on an actual device (my LG and Samsung), it doesn't

Comment: Alright, I just found what was causing the problem. It was Mapview element. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/. I didn't properly follow the configuration step, which resulted in this predicament. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
       _execute = ()=>{
       Promise.all([
        4~5 Axios requests...             
       ])
       .catch(e=>console.warn(e)) 
        .then(() => {

            this.setState({
                ...
                loaded: true,
                ...
            });
        })
}

componentDidMount() {
this._execute()
}
```

adding the catch you can spot the error